# Implementation of Linear Regression Closed Form Solution

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I wonder if you all know if backend of `sklearn's` `LinearRegression` Module uses something different to calculate the optimal beta coefficients. I implemented my own using the closed form solution

```
    if self.solver == "Closed Form Solution":
        ### optimal beta = (XTX)^{-1}XTy
        XtX = np.transpose(X, axes=None) @ X
        XtX_inv = np.linalg.inv(XtX)
        Xty = np.transpose(X, axes=None) @ y_true
        self.optimal_beta = XtX_inv @ Xty
```

However, I do not get an exact match when I print the coefficients comparing with sklearn's one. I thought that having a closed form solution may guarantee similar results (my code doesn't handle not invertible).

I noticed the MSE are not that far apart, but it just makes me wonder if my implementation is wrong (i took in account of biases)

The deviations seem to appear in the intercept:

```
SKLEARN INTERCEPT 1.2490009027033011e-15
HN INTERCEPT 4.440892098500626e-16
First Value HN 183.22200150945497
First Value SKLEARN 183.22200150945548
HN MSE 3.1084228599404546e-27
SKLEARN MSE 2.126667544039961e-25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figures are in the order of `10^-15` which means they are practically 0, and the same!

As to why there *is* a difference: you are solving the normal equations by directly inverting the `X.T @ X` matrix. On the other hand, scikit-learn uses `scipy.linalg.lstsq` [under the hood](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L668-L669), which uses [for example](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.1/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L1207) an SVD-based approach. That is, the mechanism there does *not* invert the matrix and is therefore different than yours. Note that there are many ways to solve the linear least squares problem.

But we can say that the results you get are the **same** as their way, because these operations over matrices are subject to round-off errors anyway and yours "matches" theirs (or vice versa) for many significant digits.

Comment: Thanks! This explains! So the above method guarantees even if XTX is not invertible it will work.

Comment: @ilovewt glad to be of help! There is *always* a solution for the least squares problem; so yes, one method or another should be able to solve it (to the extent possible due to aforementioned roundoff issues).